# Group Verifiable Random Function

Tags: verifiable-random-function

Is there any algorithm that allows to set up a VRF (Verifiable Random Function) from a set of Keypairs such that the knowledge of one private key and all the other public keys is enough to compute the VRF output as well as the Proof and the knowledge of all public keys allows verifying the output?

A search on my side has yielded no results but I'm not sure that I use the right keywords. I found threshold variants which when setting the threshold to 1 would work but they require a setup phase for generating the secret keys but I need to generate the group's ad hoc and I would like to avoid a high communication complexity.